# Multiple identical azure WebJobs with different parameters

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I need to run identical jobs in schedule, and they differ only in few strings.

As you may know, there is no a convenient way to create identical jobs with different parameters. For now i prefer so "codeless" way to do so, or with "as less code as possilbe".

So lets imagine they are stored in a rows of JobsConfigurations table of the website-related database.

How I can get the Job name of job being running to pick the right configuration from the table?

Thanks for help!

Comment: What is your webjob? BashScript, Executable, HttpRequest?

Comment: A background task that scans an externals data source on a schedule

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Web-Jobs#environment-settings

The `WEBJOBS_NAME` environment variable will give you the name of the current WebJob.